# nltk install saying directory is not owned by the current user and requirement already up-to-date

Tags: pip, nltk, sudo

I'm trying to install nltk by using sudo pip nltk, but am stopped with the error:

```
The directory /users/$username/library/caches/pip/http or its parent directory is 
not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. 
The directory /users/$username/Library/Caches/pip or its parent directory is 
not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. 
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (3.3)
Requirements already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from nltk) (1.4.1)
```

These error messages are shown, and I'm confused whether I already have nltk and is up-to-date or not. I checked the permission of all the parent directories and had drwx for all, so I'm confused why that message is still showing.

Please help! I'm stuck with this, and I think I had messed up with my system Python at some point.

Comment: `pip install --user -U nltk`

Comment: @alvas it says "ImportError: No module named pip._internal"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using sudo -H pip install -U nltk